# How to Log Exception in a file?

Tags: c#, wcf, logging, enterprise-library

I want to be able to do logging in every catch block. Something like this.

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
  Logger.Write(exception);
}
```

and then the settings in the configuration will pick up the Message and StackTrace property etc using customer listener.

I would like to use Enterprise Library Logging Application Block. I'm sure someone must have done this already.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Others have posted some good links on getting the Logging Application Block (LAB) working so I won't duplicate that here.

In terms of formatting your exception you have 3 choices that I can think of:

1. Use the default [`Exception.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx) implementation (it's not bad)
2. Write a Custom Formatter that integrates into the LAB.
3. Write a helper function that performs the formatting and passes the string into the Write method.

If option 1 doesn't meet your needs then I would recommend going with option 3 (since option 2 is overkill).

A simple example would be something like:

```
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Write(LogHelper.CreateExceptionString(exception));
    }

    ...

    public static string CreateExceptionString(Exception e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        CreateExceptionString(sb, e);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static void CreateExceptionString(
        StringBuilder sb,
        Exception e,
        string indent = "")
    {
        if (indent.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}Inner ", indent);
        }

        sb.AppendFormat("Exception Found:\n{0}Type: {1}",
            indent, e.GetType().FullName);
        sb.AppendFormat("\n{0}Message: {1}",
            indent, e.Message);
        sb.AppendFormat("\n{0}Source: {1}",
            indent, e.Source);
        sb.AppendFormat("\n{0}Stacktrace: {1}",
            indent, e.StackTrace);

        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            sb.Append("\n");
            CreateExceptionString(sb, e.InnerException, indent + "  ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is also helpful to include the name of the type of Exception.  But otherwise quite nice.

Comment: @Andrew: yeah or you could add some code to extract the IDictionary from the Data property.

Comment: [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-simple-Error-Log-Text-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) is another **solution**. hope helps.

Comment: I used Shaijut solution, seemed more simple one for my purpose, thanks to everybody

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft has provided **extensive** guidance on this here:  [Developing Applications Using the Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647140.aspx)

It's well worth familiarizing yourself with what they have to say, as it's quite powerful.

If you want something a little more down to earth, some working examples are provided in this blog article:  [How To Configure and Use the Logging Application Block](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/How-To-Configure-and-Use-the-Logging-Application-Block.aspx)

If you're still having trouble after reading those, edit your post with more specific details about what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Can I do something to directly pass exception object so that it gives detailed stack trace etc. which will be helpful in debugging?

Comment: You could create a pretty simple method and/or string.format template and then use it when calling Logger.Write.

Comment: The configure link goes directly to advertising.

Comment: According to your first link, this technology is now outdated.

Answer (score 2):

@iSid Is this what you are asking for

```
public static void printException(Exception ex){
                Console.WriteLine("HelpLink = {0}", ex.HelpLink);
                Console.WriteLine("Message = {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Source = {0}", ex.Source);
                Console.WriteLine("StackTrace = {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("TargetSite = {0}", ex.TargetSite);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an appropriate listener for Text files - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503582/implementing-log-file-using-enterprise-library-in-asp-net) post, its for ASP.NET but the config files work the same way across applications.

Comment: Can I do something to directly pass exception object so that it gives detailed stack trace etc. which will be helpful in debugging.