# How to write log file in c#?

Tags: c#, logging

How would I write a log file in c#?

Currently i have a timer with this statement which ticks every 20 secs:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath+"log.txt", log);
```

For everything that i want logged i do this:

```
log += "stringToBeLogged";
```

As you can assume the string log just grows and grows as the program runs. (I don't even know if there is a maximum chars per string?)

I assume that there must be better ways of doing this. i just thought that it would be heavy to write the whole file again and again for every time something is added to the log.

Comment: I suggest to discover something alike log4net

Answer (score 77, accepted):

From the performance point of view your solution is not optimal. Every time you add another log entry with +=, the whole string is copied to another place in memory. I would recommend using StringBuilder instead:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
...
sb.Append("log something");

...
// flush every 20 seconds as you do it
File.AppendAllText(filePath+"log.txt", sb.ToString());
sb.Clear();
```

By the way your timer event is probably executed on another thread. So you may want to use a mutex when accessing your `sb` object.

Another thing to consider is what happens to the log entries that were added within the last 20 seconds of the execution. You probably want to flush your string to the file right before the app exits.

Comment: [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-simple-Error-Log-Text-File-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2991300/2218697) is another **solution**. hope helps.

Comment: It will throw exception if file is in used by multiple process parallelly. also it was not a thread safe.

Comment: This seems to only work once. If you run the program again it will not append or overwrite the file.

Answer (score 73):

create a class create a object globally and call this

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;


   public class LogWriter
{
    private string m_exePath = string.Empty;
    public LogWriter(string logMessage)
    {
        LogWrite(logMessage);
    }
    public void LogWrite(string logMessage)
    {
        m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt"))
            {
                Log(logMessage, w);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter)
    {
        try
        {
            txtWriter.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            txtWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            txtWriter.WriteLine("  :");
            txtWriter.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
            txtWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution that worked gracefully!

Comment: Good, but with a static class and method, it would have been even cleaner.

Comment: Just works like a charm. Straight Forward copy paste worked.

Comment: It will throw exception if file is in used by multiple process parallelly. also it was not a thread safe.

Comment: Awesome solution! Simple to change it to a static class for .net 6 by just removing the constructor (public LogWriter...) section and adding the static keyword to the class description (public static void LogWrite).  Then the class becomes globally available without having to construct it each time you want to log something.

Comment: How are you supposed to call this? `LogWriter.LogWrite("test")`?

Comment: @user736893: For the code above, you first need to create an object. Then you can call: `LogWriter logger = new("Init logger"); logger.LogWrite("My log text");`

Answer (score 27):

Use [File.AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
File.AppendAllText(filePath + "log.txt", log);
```

Comment: +1 Just a small node: Make sure your filePath ends with a slash or add it. You should also add a new line like `File.AppendAllText(filePath + "\" + "log.txt", log + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: given that in the question he specified `log += "stringToBeLogged";` this will not work properly because of incrementally adding the same information. The should be something like `File.AppendAllText(filePath + "log.txt", 'stringToBeLogged');`

Comment: @AlexPandrea right, so if he's logging the same `log` each time, `File.WriteAllText` would suite it better, even though that is a bit much. This solution suggests to log only specific information each time (appending), not writing the full `log` variable.

Comment: @nixda, better use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of hardcoded `\ char`.

Comment: @Angel instead of `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` one can simply use `Path.Combine` method. e.g. `Path.Combine(filePath, "log.txt")`

Comment: It will throw exception if file is in used by multiple process parallelly. also it was not a thread safe.

Answer (score 18):

```
public static void WriteLog(string strLog)
    {
        StreamWriter log;
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = null;
        FileInfo logFileInfo;

        string logFilePath = "C:\\Logs\\";
        logFilePath = logFilePath + "Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";           
        logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
        logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
        if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
        if (!logFileInfo.Exists)
        {
            fileStream = logFileInfo.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
        }
        log = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        log.WriteLine(strLog);
        log.Close();
    }
```

Refer Link:
[blogspot.in](http://linktomohankumar.blogspot.in/2014/09/create-log-file-using-cnet.html)

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `StreamWriter` and `FileStream` with nested `using()` blocks.

Answer (score 11):

as posted by @randymohan, with using statements instead

```
public static void WriteLog(string strLog)
{
    string logFilePath = @"C:\Logs\Log-" + System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "." + "txt";
    FileInfo logFileInfo = new FileInfo(logFilePath);
    DirectoryInfo logDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(logFileInfo.DirectoryName);
    if (!logDirInfo.Exists) logDirInfo.Create();
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append))
    {
        using (StreamWriter log = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            log.WriteLine(strLog);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create file before doing `new FileStream`. It will create the file.

Comment: removed the file exists check

Answer (score 7):

Very convenient tool for logging is http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

You can also make something of themselves less (more) powerful. You can use [http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream (v = vs.110). Aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream%20%28v%20=%20vs.110%29.%20Aspx)

Comment: There are heaps of good tutorials out there on Log4net. This one is where I got my start with Log4net: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial

Answer (score 7):

Add log to file with Static Class

```
 public static class LogWriter
        {
            private static string m_exePath = string.Empty;
            public static void LogWrite(string logMessage)
            {
                m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                if (!File.Exists(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt"))
                    File.Create(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt");

                try
                {
                    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt"))
                        AppendLog(logMessage, w);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            }

            private static void AppendLog(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter)
            {
                try
                {
                    txtWriter.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                    txtWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                    txtWriter.WriteLine("  :");
                    txtWriter.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
                    txtWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This class needs little bit modification:
m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 if (!File.Exists(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt")){
string s = "";
s = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
FileStream fs = File.Create(m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt");
Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("File Created:"+s+"\r\n");
 fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);fs.Close(); }Otherwise at first program start you gonna have exception

Comment: or simple close file immediately after creating

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!File.Exists(filename)) //No File? Create
{
    fs = File.Create(filename);
    fs.Close();
}
if(File.ReadAllBytes().Length >= 100*1024*1024) // (100mB) File to big? Create new
{
    string filenamebase = "myLogFile"; //Insert the base form of the log file, the same as the 1st filename without .log at the end
    if(filename.contains("-")) //Check if older log contained -x
    {
         int lognumber = Int32.Parse(filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("-")+1, filename.Length-4); //Get old number, Can cause exception if the last digits aren't numbers
         lognumber++; //Increment lognumber by 1
         filename = filenamebase + "-" + lognumber + ".log"; //Override filename
    }
    else 
    {
         filename = filenamebase + "-1.log"; //Override filename
    }
    fs = File.Create(filename);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Refer link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/163337/How-to-write-in-log-Files-in-C

Answer (score 2):

This is add new string in the file

```
using (var file = new StreamWriter(filePath + "log.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(log);
            file.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 easy ways

- StreamWriter - http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter
- Log4Net like Log4j(Java) - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log4net-Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If your application is multithreaded then in some environments file.appendalltext could give error like file already in use and if you skip that then you could lose important logs .
For that you can use
Lock object technique with file.append.. in that case it will wait for existing process to close and the write your log

This can also save you from adding other libraries in your source

Answer (score 0):

Above code will throw: Process can't access the file because it is being used by another process error because of                     File.Create(m_exePath + "\" + "log.txt"); if you will comment out this it will work as expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SolutionLogWriter
{
    public static class LogWriterClass
    {
        private static string m_exePath = string.Empty;
        public static void LogWrite(string logMessage)
        {
            m_exePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string fullpath = m_exePath + "\\" + "log.txt";
            
            if (File.Exists(fullpath))
            {
                File.Delete(fullpath);
            }
           // File.Create(fullpath);
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullpath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs))
                    AppendLog(logMessage, w);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendLog(ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        private static void AppendLog(string logMessage, TextWriter txtWriter=null)
        {
            try
            {
                txtWriter.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                txtWriter.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                txtWriter.WriteLine("  :");
                txtWriter.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
                txtWriter.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtWriter.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing a file to append to it, isn't thread safe and it's not very efficient either.  If two threads try to write to the same file at the same time, there will be an IOException.

I wrote a class back in the late 90's, upgraded it over time, then lost it back in 2010.  I threw it back together from what I remembered after I lost it.  It's still old code so could always use a major update, but it's an asynchronous text logger with multiple log types and files.  It uses FileStream() to open files and holds the handle open.  It puts new information into a another ListArray().  I did try Queue at one point, but List would most likely be better today.  It uses AutoResetEvent to trip logging after message is passed in and passes that info down to write to file.

I would most likely use List today, but it's using ArrayList() to hold the file handles.  This also blocks anything else from trying to access or modify the file while your using it.

Full class.
http://chizl.com/dl/dev/csharp/FreeThread.csharp.txt

```
private struct FileHandles
{
    public FileStream twHandle;
    public String szFileName;
    public decimal dwFileSize;
    public String szRootFileName;
}   //FileHandles

private struct TransLog
{
    public String szBuffer;
    public LOG_TYPE enumFileType;
    public String AddedDateTime;
    public bool bAddReturn;
    public String szFileName;
}   //TransLog
```

Happy hacking