# How to write a c# log file?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

So I would like to log an event in c#. For example I would like to have it log every time a button is pressed into a .txt file and the file is used each time the button(s) are selected vs creating a new .txt file. I have no idea how to do this or even where to start. I do not want some extravagant code base to do it with. Does anyone know a quick, simple and to the point way of doing this?

Using VS 2015 with .NET 4.5 target framework.

Comment: In general "what are way to do X" questions are too broad for SO. You may consider reading older identical questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185015/how-to-write-log-file-in-c to improve your post and make it more narrow scoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for NLog, check the official [tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial).

Your finally code will look something like this:

using NLog;

```
public class YourClass
{
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public void ButtonWasPressedEvent()
  {
    logger.Info("Thanks for pressing dude!");
  }
}
```

The installation can be donde using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/), that should be very simple.

Comment: Gotta love NLog! I was typing the samething up and saw your answer came in :)

Comment: Thank you good sir! This is perfect!!

Answer (score 1):

The venerable [`log4net`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi) is the Apache Foundation solution for a .NET logger based on a java predecessor, `log4j`.

It is also [installable via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) but does require some non-trivial configuration due to its power and flexibility.  [`log4net`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download_log4net.cgi) can be configured in code or in the project configuration files (`app.config` or `web.config`).

Logs can be stored in flat files or in a database system of your choosing, or both, via the extensive set of available `appenders`.  For example, the `RollingFileAppender` writes to a file which "rolls over" (starts a new file) at a specified size or interval:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Multiple appenders can be used concurrently to direct log entries to multiple destinations.  Also, multiple loggers can be defined, each with their own set of appenders.

[The full feature set is listed here.](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example from MSDN, it covers the file part.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx