# How can I log something into output window in Run Without Debugging state?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, logging

I'm using Visual Studio and developing ASP.net MVC application, I want to log some text when I run my app in **Run Without Debugging** state for debugging purposes.

I don't know what to do! I can log my texts into a log file using `System.StreamWriter` class, but is there a class in .net framework that does this?

Comment: @ Mohamad, any update? Could you get the answer for this issue?

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT no sir.. I'm waiting...

Comment: @ Mohamad, what the log is? Is it the Exception messages or just custom output messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the StreamWriter and Log4Net are the workaround I often use:

For the Exception messages, some community members think about using custom code with StringBuilder like this case：

[How to Log Exception in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989401/how-to-log-exception-in-a-file/2991300#2991300)

[How to write log file in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185015/how-to-write-log-file-in-c)

If they are really not the answer you want to use, I suggest submit a feature request to the product team, of course, if you accept this suggestion, I can help you submit it:)

Answer (score 1):

Litterally the first result in google for "C# detect debugger" :
Use `Debugger.IsAttached` as described here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached(v=vs.110).aspx

And I'd suggest that you look into log4net for your logs instead of using streamwriters, it'll give you much more flexibility.

Comment: @ Mohamad, I agree with Foxtrot's suggestion, log4net would be a good answer if you want to get the output information without debugging the app. Of course, generally we collect the debugging logs in the output window:)