# How can I save a rolling flat file trace listener on another machine in LAN?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, flat-file, tracelistener

Hi I'm using Enterprise Library 5, I defined rolling flat file trace listener, to save my logs to a file, how can I address this file to be saved on another machine on LAN?

Comment: Instead of or in addition to saving it to local disk?

Comment: don't differ instead or addition to saving it to local disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but this Q seems to have all the config for tracing to a log file using ent lib: [Implementing Log file using Enterprise Library in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503582/implementing-log-file-using-enterprise-library-in-asp-net)  The relevant section is "listeners/filename"

And to log to another machine, it's just a matter of NTFS permissions and the path

You need to have the code running under a domain account that can write to the remove file (or two local accounts with the same password for a workgroup scenario)

The path will either be \machinename\sharedFolderName or \ipAddress\sharedFolderName or y:\ if you map a letter to the drive.

Comment: thanks, my problem was incorrect permissions, after set correct permissions on Shared folder, my problem solved.